# .replace not replacing all chars [NODEJS]

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, replace

I've searched all around the web for a response to this question,

Why do my .replace only replace chars that doesnt have any other char behind

My code is :
`const fixedstring = string.replace('&', '^&')`

When i enter : &notepad.exe& has a string, it give me the output ^&notepad.exe& instead of ^&notepad.exe^&

Can someone help me ? (i've tried the /g)

Thanks for the guy that will help me or just read my post, thanks !

Comment: You can only use the `/g` if you're using regex to find the char to replace.  You're using a string, not regex.  Did you try `.replace(/&/g, '^&')` ?

Comment: Yes psikai, it doesnt change any of  the &

Comment: OH wait, i don't put any ^ in the .replace ?

Comment: I need to replace all & to ^&

Comment: https://prnt.sc/O9ETk-k0YVsa

Comment: See my answer, my suggestion works

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the global flag `/g` unless you are using regex to find the characters to replace.  You are currently using a string to find, which will only match the first instance.

Instead, use the regex:

```
.replace(/&/g, "^&")
```

Here is a working example.

```js
const stringToReplace = "&notepad.exe&"

const replaced = stringToReplace.replace(/&/g, '^&')

console.log(replaced)
```

Comment: To use a string with the behavior of a global regex, you can also use [`String#replaceAll`](https://mdn.io/String.replaceAll)

Comment: Yes, but he's not using replaceAll.  So I'm explaining why it didn't work with his implementation.  `replaceAll` is a valid answer, and you should post that as an answer if you think another solution is possible.

Comment: Thought it was minor enough to not necessitate a seperate answer, mb.

Comment: It's no less significant than my answer.  Perfectly valid :)